# Intuition behind a conditional probability problem

Tags: probability, self-study, intuition

I was watching the Harvard's statistics course and came across this problem (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JzDvVgNDxo8) 9:30. 
Pick two cards from a deck of 52 cards what is the probability of getting two aces given:

1/At least one of them is ace

2/ One of them is ace of spades

The math calculation is fine. But I cannot understand the lecturer's explanation to the second problem. How one can tell the answer is $3/51$ without calculating? And how to understand the difference between the two scenarios intuitively?

Here is my attempt. The probability of the second problem is the $p(A \cup B)$ where A is the probability of one card being ace of spades and B is the probability of one card being an ace other than ace of spades. 
Because $p(A)=1$ ( it is given by the problem), I can assume it is the sample space. So $p(A\cup B)$ is just $p(B)$, in which there are 51 cards with 3 aces.

But I believe that understanding is false, since the same thing can apply to the first problem. But clearly the answers to the first problem are either equal nor twice the second one.